# In Java, how can I fix this nullPointerException in a while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nullpointerexception, null

In a java file I'm consistently having a runtime error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` at a line with a while loop and need to find a way to avoid this nullPointerException.

My current code at this line looks like this :

```
while (b.isOnBoard(row-i, col-i) && b.getState(row-i, col-i).equals(yourcolor))
{
    count++; 
    i++;
}
```

The object `b` is basically an 8 by 8 matrix "board" for the game othello. The method `isOnBoard` will return a boolean, and the method `getState` will return either my players color, my opponents color(`yourcolor`), or `null`. I don't understand why any of these returning null though would cause a nullPointerException. 
Can anyone tell me what would be causing this error and how to fix it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the method getState will return either my players color, my opponents color(yourcolor), **or null**

If `getState` returns null, which you say it might, `b.getState(row-i, col-i).equals(yourcolor)` will throw `NullPointerException`.

To avoid it, change the condition to :

```
while (b.isOnBoard(row-i, col-i) && b.getState(row-i, col-i) != null && b.getState(row-i, col-i).equals(yourcolor))
```

Of course, if `b` may be null (which is impossible to tell based on the little code you provided), that would also cause a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: b is not null, I am certain of that. It's used multiple times throughout the rest of my code without error... And thank you. Earlier I was doing `!b.getState(row-i, col-i).equals(mycolor) && !b.getState(row-i, col-i).equals(null)` and that caused the same error. Why does `!= null` work but not `!b.getState(row-i, col-i).equals(null)` ?

Comment: @namore  You can't call any method on a null reference. Therefore `b.getState(row-i, col-i).equals(..)` throws `NullPointerException` if `b.getState(row-i, col-i)` is null.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `getState()` method can return a `null` and you call `equals()` on it.

You should never return a `null`. `null` is not a value. Use an enum or an other return type.